# Always open a file in a specific program

Tags: terminal, filesystem

I'm having an issue with forcing a file of a certain type to always open with a specific program. In this case, it's `.indd` (Adobe InDesign) files. I have Adobe CS6 installed, and also Adobe InDesign 5.5. I would like to always open `.indd` files with InDesign 5.5.

I've tried using `Get Info > Open with: > InDesign 5.5 > Change All...` but it keeps automatically switching back to CS6, immediately after clicking `Change All...`.

Is there perhaps a way I can force this in Terminal?

Comment: Although often there's no controlling Adobe, you might try changing permissions to user read/write in all relevant directories, with BatChmod or similar, and trying Change All again.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind specifying InDesign 5.5 every time, then this command line should work:

> `open -a 'InDesign 5.5' myfile.indd`

If you're going to do this often, you can wrap it in a shell script or bash function like

> `function indd() { open -a 'InDesign 5.5' "$@" ; }`

Then you'll be able to simply say

> `indd myfile.indd`

Comment: This is quite good, though ideally it should be a little more user-friendly. Is there a way to intercept a double-click on an .indd file, and send that action to the first bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`:

`defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentTag=indd;LSHandlerContentTagClass=public.filename-extension;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.adobe.InDesign;}'`

Applying the changes requires restarting (logging out and back in isn't enough).

Rebuilding the LaunchServices database might also work, but it also resets other default applications set in Finder.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -domain local -domain system -domain user`